# Not able to server multiple S3 buckets on a single Cloudfront Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

**Case:**

I have a few S3 buckets that store my media files. I wanted to map all these s3 buckets to a single CF distribution. (their files should be accessed from different paths).

I have made a CF distribution and added 2 buckets. For the behaviour, the first bucket is on Default(*) and the second bucket is on path **nature/***.

**Issues:**

1. I am able to access the primary bucket (one with default behaviour) but not able to access the secondary bucket (with path nature/*). The error on accessing the secondary bucket is "Access Denied".

**Additional details:**

1. Both my buckets are **not** available to global access and CF is accessing them from OAI.

References:

1. https://aswinkumar4018.medium.com/amazon-cloudfront-with-multiple-origin-s3-buckets-71b9e6f8936
2. https://vimalpaliwal.com/blog/2018/10/10f435c29f/serving-multiple-s3-buckets-via-single-aws-cloudfront-distribution.html
3. https://youtu.be/5r9Q-tI7mMw

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files in the second bucket must start with a top level prefix `nature/` or else the won't resolve. CF doesn't remove the path matched when routing, it is still there. The CloudFront behavior will correctly match and send the request to the second bucket, but the path will still be `nature/...`.

If you can't move the objects in the second bucket into a `nature/` prefix, then you need a CF Function to remove this part of the path from the object key before forwarding the request to the S3 origin.

Moving all the objects include the `nature` prefix is easy but annoying. It is the best strategy because it is also cheapest (from a monetary standpoint), but may require extra overhead on your side. A CF function is easier but costly both from a money standpoint and performance, since the CF function has to be run every time.

An example CF function might be:

```js
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/nature/, '');
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed the part where I had to add a top level prefix to the bucket. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront doesn't natively support this.

The original request path is forwarded intact to the origin server, with only one exception: if the origin has an Origin Path configured, that value is added to the beginning of the path before the request is sent to the origin (and, of course, this doesn't help, here).

However, we can modify the path during CloudFront processing using a CF-Function

The function code to remove the first level from the path might look something like this:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, "/");
    return request;
}
```